# Calculating inverse of a function modulo m

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse-function

Let **f(p) = a*p + b (mod m)**
Where a and m are relatively prime.
What is the inverse function of f?

This is confusing because generally we talk about inverse of a number not a function. 
So what I understand is we have to find a function g() such that
**f(p) *g() = 1 (mod m)**

How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The same as any inverse fuction.

The functions so that $f(f^{-1}(p)) = p$.

Set $f^{-1}(p) = y$ (just so we can avoid typing

And $f(y) \equiv a*y + b \equiv p \pmod m$ and solve for $y$.

$ay + b \equiv p \pmod m$

$ay \equiv p-b \pmod m$

Now $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime so $a^{-1}$ exists.

$y \equiv a^{-1}(p -b)\pmod m$.

So $f^{-1}(p)  = a^{-1}(p-b)\pmod m$.

That's all there is to it.

For any $p \in \mathbb Z_m$ then if $K = a*y+b$ then $f^{-1}(K) = a^{-1}(K-b)= a^{-1}([ap+b] - b) \equiv a^{-1}(ap) \equiv p\pmod m$.